# WCF in windows service hosting with silverlight application

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have written WCF and hosted in windows service now when accessing the services via basic http binding, it is showing **"This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details."** Please suggest solution step by step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-domain error Silverlight + WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559666/cross-domain-error-silverlight-wcf)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for not replying but I got the solution. Please suggest if anything is not in order.

We have created WCF and hosted it in Windows Services as netTCP. Now, I created Silverlight Enabled WCF Services in Silverlight.Web Project and call netTcp service from here and Silverlight WCF enabled Services called in Silverlight Project and it is running fantastic. Before this I tried from Web Service but it is taking when large data calling from silverlight application.